# Can "good" and "well" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

I told someone I was doing good in my new community, and they thought I was talking about my well being. When I told them that I meant I was doing good in the community like in a helping out "do-gooder" sort of way, they told me that "good" and "well" can be used interchangeably in my context and *always* refer to one's well being.

But doesn't only the word "well" mean state of health to avoid misunderstandings like this? Doesn't "I've been doing good in the new community" mean I have been doing good things in the community to help out? And doesn't "I've been doing well in the new community" mean that I am healthy, not being harassed by the community members and whatnot?

Comment: The "doing things for the sake of others" meaning of "do good" is both well known and acceptable; I'm surprised the someone you spoke to was unfamiliar with it.

Comment: To answer your question, "good" and "well" cannot always be interchangeable. *I have good news*, *She's a good teacher*; *How much good can we do?* *There is good and bad in the world*; in none of these cases (and there are many more) can "good" be substituted with "well".

Comment: In your context, doing good in the community, it's clear you were talking about doing humanitarian actions which benefit everyone living in that area.

Comment: Although admittedly 'I'm doing good now I've settled here in Leigh" doesn't sound very idiomatic, and might well be taken to refer to one's own wellbeing. 'Since moving to Leigh / here, I've found quite a few areas where I feel I can make a real contribution to village life.'

Comment: Basically, the answer to the question in the title is "sometimes – but be aware that each carries different senses, that certain senses are more likely to be intended and assumed in different situations, and that 'anything that can lead to confusion **will** lead to confusion' ".

Comment: Firstly, good for you Sam!  Secondly, IMO, when in doubt, clarify.  Replace "doing good" with "volunteering", "performing good deeds", "helping out in my new community", etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Good  is common as an adverb in informal speech, especially after
>   forms of *do*: He did *good* on the test. She sees *good* with her new
>   glasses.  This use does not occur in formal speech or edited writing,
>   where the adverb *well*  is used instead: He did *well* on the test.

Please see this link for reference:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good?s=t

I hope you understand. :)

Comment: But isn't the OP talking about doing "good actions" for the community, not in his performance? "Well" also carries other meanings, "I'm doing well" is *I feel fine* or *I'm healthy*.

Comment: Yes, and the person listening to OP apparently came up with the wrong interpretation. One could debate whether OP was over-ambiguous or audience under-aware of polysemy (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Beware idiomatic expressions. "I was doing good in my new community" does not mean "I was doing good **work** in my new community" -- it means "I was prospering/ managing well in my new community." Your interlocutor cannot be faulted. This adverbial usage of *good* is informal, in the sense of "well".

*good* adverb *informal* ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/good))
well: *my mother could never cook this good*; *I’m feeling pretty good, all things considered*

Comment: Beware sweeping statements. The first page of Google returns for "she was doing good" has examples of both usages. Admittedly, 'I was doing good' is less likely to be self-aggrandisement, but that sense would not be wrong (from a linguistics point of view).

Comment: The op later clarified his statement to the lady by saying:"...helping out "do-gooder" sort of way..." In which case, it is strange that the lady and her friends insisted that good and well are interchangeable and *always* refers to well-being.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A That's all good and well. I wonder if there are any oil goods in OP's locality.